# Verb forms in "Feelin' Myself" (will.i.am song)

Tags: grammar

I have been somewhat fascinated by this song recently, for various reasons, including the peculiar lyrics. I am especially wondering about the usage of infinitive-like verb forms in several lines, such as:

*I **be** everywhere, everybody **know** me*
*Cause we **be** in the club*
*Look up in the mirror, the mirror **look** at me*
*The mirror **be** like 'baby [...]'*

I recognized some of them as similar to "X be like Y" expressions, which I found to be classified as a combination of "habitual be" and "quotative like". But there are other verbs being used in an apparently similar way, and I'm wondering if they're habitual verb aspects, subjunctive mood (my first guess), artistic license, contractions, other forms of slang/vernacular or just bad grammar.

Edit: In case it wasn't painfully obvious from the above paragraph, I have already researched "X be like Y" and that is not what my question is about. Specifically (and repeating myself again), there are other verbs being used, which are not covered by the "habitual be" and "quotative like" explanations. Also, "AAVE" is not a suitable answer to either question (it's probably true but much too vague - I'm asking about the verb forms).

Comment: That verb structure is common in African American Vernacular English: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English

Comment: Nicole is right on the target. Start reading Faulkner, as many Blacks there are using variations thereof.

Comment: @Nicole - this should be expanded into an answer, it is the correct one.

Comment: The question was closed while I was in the middle of typing it, but it looks like the link to the previous question has some detailed answers about AAVE.

Comment: Uh.. @Andrew how is this a duplicate? If you actually read my question, it should be extremely obvious that I am not asking about "X be like Y".

Comment: Your question contains the lyric "The mirror be like baby" and the answers at that question says it's AAVE (which it is).

Comment: @AndrewLeach so you read one line, ignored everything else, and single-handedly decided to close it based on that?

Comment: No, I didn't. I read your question and found an earlier question which addresses what you're asking about. What may be misleading is the question I found is linked as a duplicate of a "habitual *be* /quotative *like*" question, which I'm not sure is justified in that case.

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to analyze the grammar of hip hop music.  Their main criteria is that it rhymes, flows with the music, and makes sense to them.  Whether it makes sense to anyone else is not much of a concern to many artists, nor is grammar.  Matter of fact, many will intentionally speak broken English to disrespect a culture they don't like, prove they're down, fit in with peers, or some combination thereof.

Comment: @publicwireless So you're saying it's not AAVE but just artistic license?

Comment: @aditsu  In this case a little of both.  Don't stress yourself out trying to analyze song lyrics (especially hip hop) for grammar since as I mentioned before, it's not a priority

Comment: If it turns out that the answer is "it's AAVE" then I'll close it as a dupe. But maybe that's not the answer.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен Thanks for that. I don't think "it's AAVE" can be a suitable answer, even if it's true, because it says nothing more than "some people just talk like that". A proper answer would need some more details about how these verb form are classified and how they're supposed to be interpreted. The only question for which "it's AAVE" is the answer would be something like "What is the name of the English dialect commonly spoken by black people in the USA?"

Comment: You give boldest examples of 'be like' and then say the question is not about that. So this is unclear. Is your question then about 'know' and 'look'? Those aren't anything like 'be'. They are inflected normally in AAVE like that (without the 's' that standard English has).

Comment: @Mitch I highlighted 5 verbs, only the last one is a "be like" and I mainly included it for completeness. My question is about all of them, but especially about the first 4, since *assuming I identified it correctly*, I already know what the last one is (habitual "be" + quotative "like"). I wonder, for example, if all the "be"s in there are instances of habitual "be". And I'd also like to know what "know" and "look" are; indeed they are possibly quite different from "be".

Comment: If you look up the definition of 'habitual be', those tend to go with a progressive ('-ing') and tend to mean 'usually', rather than right now. From that, none of the instances in this song seem to be habitual to me (I am using weasel words because all my statements are arguable). Also 'know' and 'look' are very different from 'be' because they are not being used as a grammatical markers (like 'be') but as  transitive verbs.

Comment: @Mitch Well, wikipedia has examples like "everybody be so choked up over gifts and everything, they don't be too hungry" - no "ing" there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In African American dialect, is it "I like" or "I likes"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/488923/in-african-american-dialect-is-it-i-like-or-i-likes) 'Following the rules of African American dialect, one rule is to drop the 's' on a verb when using third person singular, i.e. "she like, he like"' // ... // '
In AAVE present tense verbs other than be do not change to reflect person or number, so it's like for all cases.' (Jon Hanna)

Answer (score -1):

I would discourage you from analyzing or learning from a pop song, as grammar is usually bad, and often intentionally so.

For example in your example,

> Look up in the mirror, the mirror **look** at me

This is probably just to keep the flow of the song and not cram too many sylables into one line. In grammatically correct English, it would be "the mirror looks at me."

Similarly,

> Cause we **be** in the club

and

> The mirror be like baby

I would say the the use of "be" here, in place of the correct conjugated forms of the verb (*are* and *is* respectively) is to make it a bit less of a mouthful, i.e. make it sound better and be easier to say, especially in an (assumedly) fast-paced song.

---

**N.B.** As mentioned in the comments, this could be [AAVE (African American Vernacular English)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English)

Comment: Basically you are saying it's artistic license, then you turn around and say it "could be AAVE". In AAVE, at least some of those verbs are not grammatically incorrect, but are deliberately used that way, with a distinct meaning (e.g. the habitual aspect)

Comment: This is an extremely poor answer. The song is clearly in AAVE, and as such, the grammar is correct. You haven't attempted to explain the grammar at all, except to dismiss it as incorrect, so this doesn't answer the question.