# Is it Ever Correct to Omit "to" Before "Be"?

Tags: verbs, be

If I had the sentence:

*Jane requires Nathan **to be** with her when she studies.*

Would it also be correct to phrase it:

*Jane requires Nathan **be** with her when she studies.*

I suppose if I replaced *requires* with *needs* then omitting the *to* sounds wrong.

Is it possible to omit the *to* (in the second example sentence) and still be correct? And if not, why is it incorrect?

EDIT:
Suppose the sentence were for a video-game:

Bob has a 150% bonus that requires Frank **to be** in the formation for the bonus to apply.

Bob has a 150% bonus that requires Frank **be** in the formation for the bonus to apply.

Comment: Well, if needs be ... :)

Comment: This is not an omission of "to". It is a completely different construction. Jane requires *(that)* Nathan *(should)* be with her.

Comment: Okay, made an edit to the original post, is the situation any different in the new examples or is it still a different construction?

Comment: What makes you think the edition would make any difference from the first example?

Comment: How could that possibly be??

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/242414/verb-forms-in-feelin-myself-will-i-am-song

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases it's simply two different constructions:

> Jane requires something.
>   Bob has a 150% bonus that requires something for the bonus to apply.

In the first construction, *something* is replaced by an extended infinitive with *to*.

In the second, instead of *something* we use a subordinate clause:

> that Nathan is with her when she studies
>   that Frank is in the formation

To spell it out:

> Jane requires that Nathan is with her when she studies.
>   Bob has a 150% bonus that requires that Frank is in the formation for the bonus to apply.

However, in this kind of situation it is natural to use the mood that is often known as subjunctive and that is always identical to the infinitive (without *to*!) in all persons and numbers:

> that Nathan be with her when she studies
>   that Frank be in the formation

Once you do this, the word *that* isn't really necessary any more to indicate that a subordinate clause follows. You can just leave it out - leading to your two examples.

PS: It is likely that this does not work in all variants of English. It certainly works in American English, but in British English there may be some restriction on the verb that is not satisfied by *require*. See the discussion for chasly from UK's question for details.

Comment: Thank you! Does this mean both sentence constructions are correct (in both cases)? Or is the second construction incorrect? (I have your answer and another answer, but the two seem to conflict.)

Comment: The second construction is obsolescent but not obsolete. You didn't recognise it, and apparently chasly also misinterpreted it as an extended infinitive with *to* that is missing its *to*. It's probably a matter of age and of how many old books you have read. (It's one of those situations where non-native speakers who have read lots of old books have an advantage over most native speakers.) If you want it to be easily readable by young readers, choose the first construction or don't omit *that* in the second.

Answer (score 0):

**1.**

Jane requires Nathan to be with her when she studies. [correct]

Jane requires Nathan be with her when she studies. [incorrect]

Jane requires that Nathan [should] be with her when she studies. [acceptable]

**2.**

Jane needs Nathan to be with her when she studies. [correct]

Jane needs Nathan be with her when she studies. [incorrect]

Jane needs that Nathan be with her when she studies. [incorrect]

3.

Bob has a 150% bonus that requires Frank to be in the formation for the bonus to apply. [correct]

Bob has a 150% bonus that requires Frank be in the formation for the bonus to apply. [incorrect]

Bob has a 150% bonus that requires that Frank be in the formation for the bonus to apply. [justifiable but clumsy and not at all idiomatic IMO]

---

The difference can be explained in terms of the English subjunctive. However I won't expand on that unless requested. There is some controversy about precisely what constitutes subjunctive in English.

Comment: Jane requires Nathan be with her when she studies. [incorrect] Jane requires that Nathan be with her when she studies. [correct]. In these 2 sentences, the *only* difference is using *that*. Why would you say not using *that* is incorrect?

Comment: @Rathony - I say it is incorrect because it is not done that way in the English language. If you consult any grammar book you will find that I am correct. As for 'why', well that is a very deep question that can be asked about any construct in any natural language. I gave a partial answer when I made reference to the subjunctive. Maybe I need to expand my answer. I don't have time right now but I'll do so later.

Comment: Will the down-voter please explain. I welcome constructive criticism. However, without feedback I cannot easily improve my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I changed my mind. Thanks. Drive-by downvoting seems to be going on right now. I don't think this reply deserves it and will make it right.

Comment: I've undone my accepted answer and will leave it neutral for the time being. I'm conflicted now. (Also, I can't downvote because I'm new so it wasn't me.)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with 1b or 3b, at least; I don't see why *be* can't be used in a jussive subjunctive as opposed to any other verb. It may sound old-fashioned in speech, but I write with this construction often, for instance, in business proposals: *We recommend our staff conduct the training. We suggest there be at least two (2) hours of training devoted to each set of reports.*

Comment: @choster - The difference is that 'suggest' and 'recommend' can be used that way and 'require'  can't. We can say, "I suggest you go home" but would anyone say, "I require you go home."? No they would say "I require you to go home" or "I require that you go home".  If you can show me any evidence to the contrary in published works, I'd be very interested.

Comment: @user2348797 - Not a problem. I don't have time right now but when I do, I'll provide evidence. In the meantime you might be interested to read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive - and also this http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv201.shtml

Comment: @chaslyfromUK It may not be as common, but it's in use. *… 48 states and the District of Columbia require you be licensed, registered or certified*; *Most price protection programs, however, will require you be vigilant in catching price drops*; *But Judge Consuelo Callahan… said what the Arizona rules mandate of Scheehle does not require he be paid.*

Comment: @choster  - Thanks for that. I wonder if it occurs other than in legal-type documents.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: I now suspect that we are dealing with a difference between variants of English. While this construction sounds natural to me with *require*, it does make me feel of Americans in a way that the same construction with *suggest* and *recommend* definitely does not.