# In African American dialect, is it "I like" or "I likes"?

Tags: verbs, dialects, african-american-vernacular-english

Following the rules of African American dialect, one rule is to drop the 's' on a verb when using third person singular, i.e. "she like, he like" - my question is - for the **first** person singular, would "I likes" be correct in dialect, or should it be "I like"? without the 's'?

Comment: I dont really know the formal rules of this, but i am almost certain its "I like".

Comment: “I likes” to me sounds more likely to occur in various dialects in England than in the US.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AAVE present tense verbs other than *be* do not change to reflect person or number, so it's *like* for all cases. Since most "standard" dialects including SAE only have a difference for the third person singular, with all other people and number using the same form, it's only noticeable in this case.